# How can I keep warm an AWS Lambda invoked from API Gateway with proxy integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have defined a lambda function that is invoked from API Gateway with proxy integration. Thus, I have defined an eager resource path for it:

[image]

And referenced my lambda function:

[image]

My lambda is able to process request like `GET /myresource`, `POST /myresource`.

I have tried this strategy to keep it warm, described in [acloudguru](https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm-9d7e1aa6e2f0). It consists of setting up a CloudWatch event rule that invokes the lambda every 5 minutes to keep it warm. Unfortunately it isn't working.

This is the behaviour I have seen:

- After some period, let's say 20 minutes, I call `GET /myresource` from API Gateway and it takes around 15 seconds. Subsequent requests last ~30ms. The CloudWatch event is making no difference...
- Let's suppose another long period without calling the gateway. If I go to the Lambda console and invoke it directly (test button) it answers right away (less than 1ms) with a 404 (that's normal because my lambda expects `GET /myresource` or `POST /myresource`).

[image]

Immediately after this lambda console execution I call `GET /myresource` from API Gateway and it still takes ~20 seconds. That is to say, the function was still cold despite having being invoked from the Lambda console. This might explain why the CloudWatch event doesn't work since it calls the lambda without setting the method/resource-url.

So, how can I make this particular case with API Gateway with proxy integration + Lambda stay warm to prevent those slow first request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denis is quite right about the non deterministic lambda behaviour regarding the number of containers hit by CloudWatch events. I'll follow his advice to improve the startup time.

On the other hand I have managed to make my CloudWatch events hit the lambda function properly, reducing (in many cases) the number of cold starts.

I just had to add an additional controller mapped to "/" with a hardcoded response:

```
@Controller("/")
class WarmUpController {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    @Get
    fun warmUp(): String {
        logger.info("Warming up")
        return """{"message" : "warming up"}"""
    }
}
```

With this in place the default (/) invocation from CloudWatch does keep the container warm most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

As of now (2019-02-27) [1], A periodic CloudWatch event rule does not deterministically solve the cold start issue. But a periodic CloudWatch event rule will reduce the probability of cold starts.

The reason is it's upto the Lambda server to decide whether to use a new Lambda container instead of an existing container to process an incoming request. Some of the related details regarding how Lambda containers are reused is explained in [1]

In order to reduce the cold start time (not to reduce the number cold starts), can you try followings? 1. increasing the memory allocated to the function, 2. reduce the deployment package size (eg- remove unnecessary dependencies), and 3. use a language like NodeJS, Python instead of Java, .Net

[1]According to reinvent session, (39:50 at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdzV04T_kec), the Lambda team expects to improve the VPC cold start latency in Lambda.

[2] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

Comment: I appreciate you advice Denis